# How to switch off Akamai caching for dynamic html files?

Tags: http, caching, httprequest, akamai

I run wordpress site and am using Akamai for caching. I have a link on every page so the user can switch between desktop and mobile site at any point. This link once clicked stores cookie which is passed to server with every request and so server knows if needs to return mobile site or desktop version.

Now when I access via "origin" it all works fine as it skips Akamai caching. However when accessing site as normal, so with Akamai caching, the link doesn't do anything. I'm assuming its because as far as Akamai is concerned its exactly the same url request and as Akamai has already its cached version it returns the same page ignoring the cookie all together.

Is there any way to tell akamai directly from my php files in wordpress not to cache html and do it only for images,css etc?

Or maybe is there a setting in Akamai itself where this can be specified?

If not then what other options would I have to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are a number of ways to do this. The easiest way would be to do a no cache on specific file extensions such as .html

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak the files to be or not to be cached in AKAMAI through "Configuration Attributes and Digital Properties" screen.
On "Time To Live Rules", you can define path and their caching policy.

Apart from that if you want to validate if a particular web resource id rendered from AKAMAI or not, you can use Fiddler and a particular PRAGMA header.
Refer link [Validate if web resource is served from AKAMAI (CDN)??](http://technowide.net/2014/06/25/validate-web-resource-served-akamai-cdn/) for more details.